# Changing default locale from Terminal and got "hash collision"

Tags: locale

I am currently translating the User Interface of meld for users in Taiwan.  I launched the compiled version but the system do not display with the required locale.  I checked my system settings and found the system pushed me to use zh_HK.  I cannot change my computer to zh_TW, so I seeked for help from Google.  I found an article about changing the default locale from Terminal, so here is what I get:

```
tom@BKGOVWKS04:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
[sudo] password for tom: 
Generating locales...
  en_HK.UTF-8... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
  zh_HK.UTF-8... up-to-date
  zh_TW.UTF-8... hash collision (1741690699) zh_TW.utf8, es_CU.utf8
failed
Generation complete.
tom@BKGOVWKS04:~$
```

hash collision? What is it? Did I do something wrong before?  How can I correct it?

Comment: Can you please try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall locales` and let us know if it makes a difference.

Comment: Succeed.  Both the GUI and CLI fixed.  Here is the result:
tom@BKGOVWKS04:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall locales
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,695 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main locales all 2.13+git20120306-12.1 [2,695 kB]
Fetched 2,695 kB in 2s (918 kB/s)

Comment: (Reading database ... 330476 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../locales_2.13+git20120306-12.1_all.deb ...
    Unpacking locales (2.13+git20120306-12.1) over (2.13+git20120306-12.1) ...
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
    Setting up locales (2.13+git20120306-12.1) ...
    Generating locales...
      en_HK.UTF-8... up-to-date
      en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
      zh_HK.UTF-8... up-to-date
      zh_TW.UTF-8... up-to-date
    Generation complete.

The es_CU.utf8 coming from nowhere is gone.